# Preencher formulário em PDF a partir de HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

É possível preencher apenas os campos editáveis de um formulário em PDF através de dados em HTML e continuar deixando estes campos como editáveis no próprio PDF? (formulário em PDF)

Comment: Você quer fazer um formulário HTML que envie os dados para o arquivo PDF preenchendo os capos editáveis do mesmo. Por aue exatamente?

Comment: Não tem formulário HTML. É apenas texto em HTML que quero passar para um formulário PDF (PDF editável)